# Replace text -> (how)?

Tags: command-line-interface, fart

So im trying to replace some text in a large .txt file.

Im using the open source tool "fart"

```
FART c:\test\test.txt c:\test\test_new.txt "->" ""
```

I want to remove all "->" in my text file. But when using the code i posted above, it seem like it dose not understand >. That symbol will just post all the options in fart.

is there a fast way to replace all "->" with nothing? it dose not have to be fart, it just have to be really fast.

Hope someone can help me out.

Comment: what does this have to do with powershell?

Comment: If you want to use powershell and a script, use the the StreamReader library for big files. (https://www.sqlshack.com/reading-file-data-with-powershell/) 

There are tons of examples available in the web. If you want to have an exe, do it in c#. Fart is probably fine as well, but not too common to use afaik so you will not get any specific support for deeper questions

Comment: I have voted to close your question, which is 'how do I use the [tag:command-line-interface] of [tag:fart]?'. This site is not for questions about software, and certainly not for those where you should be able to get the answer by reading the manual. I have removed your invalid [tag:batch-file], [tag:cmd], and [tag:powershell] tags, as none of those were relevant to your question. I woud further ask that you delete your off topic question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `--` to tell FART that the options have ended and the only thing that follows are the search and replace strings.

```
fart c:\test\test.txt c:\test\test_new.txt -- "->" ""
```

Using `--` this way is a convention that many command line tools, especially Linux/*nix, share.